# Strange rules for complex multiplication with Infinity

Tags: matlab

Is there any explanation for following contradictory results in MATLAB?

```
>> Inf*0
ans =
   NaN

>> Inf*(0+1i)
ans =
            0 +        Infi
```

Is it a bug or is there any explanation for this?

**UPDATE**:

Interestingly that MATLAB, Maple & Mathematica all give the same results. BUT programming languages follow different philosophy. Check for example [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) Annex G 5.1.6. Same for FORTRAN. Well respected [GNU MPC](http://multiprecision.org/) library also gives NaN + Inf*i.

My conclusion is that we need better & uniform semantic for complex operations and probably separate notion for complex infinity.

Comment: This behavior violates the rule that (a+ib) * (c+id) = ac-bd + i(ad+bc) and everything derived from this rule. Calculating according to this rule would give NaN. Is the rule defined anywhere?

Comment: See also a more thorough discussion of this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031966/why-does-inf-0j1-evaluate-to-inf-nanj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not contradictory behavior since `0+1i` is a number, albeit complex; the `Inf` does not distribute because of this.  And since `0+1i` does not have a magnitude of `0`, multiplying it by `Inf` has a defined behavior; infinite magnitude in this instance. Apparently the arithmetic is such that the infinity is explicitly complex only, but that delves into dealing with infinity in the complex plane, which is an [interesting discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Complex_analysis) on its own.

If you change the number to one with zero magnitude, you have the same (Real) behavior:

```
>> Inf*(1+0i)   % Real with magnitude 1
ans =
   Inf

>> Inf*(0+1i)   % Imaginary with magnitude 1
ans =
   0.0000 +    Infi

>> Inf*(1/sqrt(2)+1i/sqrt(2))  % Complex with magnitude 1
ans =
      Inf +    Infi

>> Inf*(0+0i)  % Imaginary with magnitude 0
ans =
   NaN
```

Multiplying `Inf` by `0` and `0i` separately also produces a `NaN`.

```
>> Inf*0+Inf*0i
ans =
   NaN
```

Comment: Good points, thank you. But still there should be some formal definition of multiplication which takes all these cases in to account. Riemann sphere?

Comment: The set of complex numbers does not include infinity.  The Riemann sphere is an extension of the set of complex numbers with a unique infinity.  `MATLAB` is instead extending the set by adding several infinities, all with the same modulus, but with different arguments.